# Truth table logic (includes negation and conjunction) (Haskell)

Tags: logic

¬(P ∧ ¬Q)

Complete truth table for the following sentence.

EDIT: The image below shows where I am at in the process. With all of the negation symbols, I'm getting a little confused on how to fill out the connectives.

$$\def\true{\mathsf T}\def\false{\mathsf F}
\begin{array}{|l:l|l:l:l:l:l|}\hline
\rm P &\rm Q &\lnot &\rm(P &\land &\lnot &\rm Q)\\\hline
\true &\true &      &\true &      &      &\true \\\hdashline
\true &\false&      &\true &      &      &\false\\\hdashline
\false&\true &      &\false&      &      &\true \\\hdashline
\false&\false&      &\false&      &      &\false\\\hline
\end{array}$$

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBA7f.png]

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You are supposed to show the work you have done so far.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I have included an image into the question. The connectives are throwing me off. I have a very rough around the edges knowledge of logic, and when negation symbols start getting involved, I get shaken up

Answer (score 1):

[image: Truth table drawn out in stages]The usual method is to write every combination of T/F for the variables, and then add columns putting the expression together bit by bit.  So make a column for the values of $\neg Q$, and then use that column and the P column to construct the $P \land \neg Q$ column, and finally make one more column with the negation of that to get your final expression.

Comment: +1 for writing it in a blackboard!

Answer (score 1):

The rightmost $\lnot$ column contains the negation of the $Q$ column. Obviously this is $\lnot Q$

The $\land$ column contains the conjunction of the $P$ and rightmost $\lnot$ column. This is $P\land\lnot Q$.

The leftmost $\lnot$ column contains negation of the $\land$ column.  This is $\lnot(P\land\lnot Q)$.

So, here is the first row:

$$\def\true{\mathsf T}\def\false{\mathsf F}
\def\trueblue{\color{blue}{\mathsf T}}\def\falseblue{\color{blue}{\mathsf F}}
\begin{array}{|c:c|c:c:c:c:c|}\hline
      &      &\tiny\rm\lnot(P\land\lnot Q)      &      &\tiny\rm P\land\lnot Q      &\tiny\lnot\rm Q      &      \\\hdashline
\rm P &\rm Q &\lnot &\rm(P &\land &\lnot &\rm Q)\\\hline
\true &\true &\trueblue      &\true &\falseblue      &\falseblue      &\true \\\hdashline
\true &\false&      &\true &      &      &\false\\\hdashline
\false&\true &      &\false&      &      &\true \\\hdashline
\false&\false&      &\false&      &      &\false\\\hline
\end{array}$$